# Abstract methods do not specify a body - Interface trying to implement super interface method giving compile time error in JDK 8

Tags: methods, interface, java-8, abstract, implementation

I'm currently trying to learn `JDK 8` features and its new that we can do method's implementation inside an interface. Like this

```
interface SuperInt {
    public static void method1() {  // completely qualified
        System.out.println("method1");
    }

    public default void method2() {   // completely qualified
        System.out.println("method2");
    }

    public void method3();   // completely qualified
}
```

But when I tried to extend this interface and tried to implement it in a sub interface is giving a compile time error.

> **Abstract methods do not specify a body**

```
interface SubInt extends SuperInt {
    public void method3() {  //  compile time error

    }
}
```

If it is ok to keep implemented methods in an interface, then why it would give error while we try to implement an abstarct method of super interface in its sub interface?

Comment: ***Side note***: The methods defined in interfaces are by *default* `public`.

Comment: @nullpointer just say that I was giving a little help to compiler :)

Comment: Not even considered by the compiler as they are redundant, you might just being explicit about the contracts, given that from Java9 onwards you can also define `private` methods in the interfaces.

Comment: you just forgot to add `default` to the method in `SubInt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot implement an abstract method within an `interface` and **`SubInt` is still an `interface` and not a `class`** as

```
interface SubInt extends SuperInt
```

is trying to ***extend*** the interface and *not implementing* it. To implement it you shall use

```
public class SuperIntImpl implements SuperInt {
    @Override
    public void method3() {

    }
}
```

On the other hand, the `method2` is a `default` method which is why it compiles with an implementation.

---

Related to the example of `SubInt` and `SuperInt` with default overridden implementation in `SubInt`, hopefully this example would clarify things:

```
public interface SuperInt {
    void method3(); 
    void method4();
}

public interface SubInt extends SuperInt {
    @Override 
    default void method3() { 
        System.out.println("Inside SubInt");
    }
}
```

while an implementation of `SubInt` may now choose to override or not the `method3`, **it is a must** still to implement `method4` as

```
public class SubIntImpl implements SubInt {
    @Override
    public void method4() {

    }
    // can reuse the implementation of the 'method3'
}
```

and for any implementation of `SuperInt` it would still be a must to have its own implementation of both the `method3` and `method4`

```
public class SuperIntImpl implements SuperInt {

    @Override
    public void method3() {
         // must have my own implementation
    }

    @Override
    public void method4() {
        // must have my own implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: "is trying to extend the interface and not implementing it." which I think the OP already knowns given they said "But when I tried to extend this interface and tried to implement it "

Comment: @Aomine I guess the highlighted part answers that.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "You cannot implement an abstract method within an interface" so if I had `interface SuperInt {
    public void method3();  
}

interface SubInt extends SuperInt {
    public default void method3() {  

    }
}` then in my understanding I would say "method3" in `SubInt` implements "method3" in `SuperInt`.

Comment: @Aomine `default` methods are not `abstract` then.. and in the example provided by you, the `SubInt` explicitly defines its default implementation of `method3` (of course overriden) so that classes implementing it might use that default implementation while classes derived from SuperInt might still choose to have a different contract.... and what I meant was that, when in an interface you don't provide a classifier defining the method, it fallbacks to being `abstract` and hence you cannot have it implemented.

Comment: Of course @nullpointer default methods cannot be abstract if we try to remove definition of `method2` and end it with a semicolon it gives error. But I'm sorry I felt you previous comment inscrutable, can you please explain it in your answer. One more doubt as what @Aomine expalined in the answer for making the method default will result in making `method3()` entirely different from the super interface right?

Comment: *for making the method default will result in making method3() entirely different from the super interface right?* ... maybe you should also not let go the basic point, that interfaces cannot be used without their implementations.. so understand it as, the class implementation of `SubInt` would use its contracts thereon while the implementations of the `SuperInt` would use their contracts.

Answer (score 3):

> But when I tried to extend this interface and tried to implement it in
>   a sub interface is giving a compile time error.

You didn't try to implement it, instead, you're defining a new abstract method.

```
public void method3() {  //  compile time error

}
```

if you want to provide implementation then prefix the method declaration with the `default` keyword:

```
public default void method3() {  //  compile time error
      ...
}
```

Comment: it worked, but the `default` keyword ain't needed in the case of `class` right? And by saying **you're defining a new abstract method**, you are telling that `method3` of super interface is not coming to sub interface?

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran "but the default keyword ain't needed in the case of class right? " default methods *can only be used in interfaces*. when your class implements a given interface it's signing a contract meaning it will be forced to implement all _non-default_ methods. as for "by saying you're defining a new abstract method, you are telling that method3 of super interface is not coming to sub interface? " what I am saying is "method3" overrides the "method3" in `SuperInt`.

Comment: I've edited my comment. Say I've an abstract class with an abstract method I'm extending it into another class. In the new class I'll be implementing the abstract method rather than overriding it. I guess giving definition to an abstract method is `implementation` and redefining a super class method is `oveerriding`

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran correct. When you implement an `interface` for the first level of inheritance e.g. say `SuperIntImpl`  you **implement** an abstract method(`implements`). Then if another class `SubIntImpl extends SuperIntImpl` and defines the same method, it would **override** the implementation for its instances(`@Override`). I guess JDK is using the keywords with a decent analogy to their purpose.

Comment: Now my confusion has increased. One why this `default` keyword is made mandatory and from what @Aomine said **"method3" overrides the "method3" in SuperInt**! How can we override an unimplemented method??

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran Tried explaining that in the [comment to my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53570510/abstract-methods-do-not-specify-a-body-interface-trying-to-implement-super-int#comment94005930_53570530) as well.